# The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid. error while configure external tomcat 8 with netbeans 7

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, external, server

I am getting an error like The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.
While adding an external server with my netebans.

Tomact works fine now. but how to add tomcat to the netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know that tomcat8 is not compatible with netbeans7, so just download netbeans7 and try to add tomcat8 and it will work.

$Mohammed

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility issue exists between Tomcat 8 & NetBeans 7. 
Use any version of Tomcat below 8.
For eg. 7.0.29 works fine :)